# Finding if lastname exists in database

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to write a simple IF statement on checking if a lastname in a database exists before a user hits the submit button to create a new record. Here is my code so far, I'm  new to Django and Python so the help is appreciated.

I made a variable called lastname, the thought process here is when the user hits submit, it checks the database first before the commit to warn them with a popup if the lastname exists to prevent duplicate records. It would actually be really cool to have it when a person exits the field for it to run the script before they finish filling out the form to save time.

```py
#views.py

from .models import StudentCheck
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from forms.forms import NewStudentForm


def NewStudentFormCheckList (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewStudentForm(request.POST) 
        lastname = StudentCheck.lastname
        if form.is_valid():
            newstudent= form.save()


    else:
        form = NewStudentForm()    

    return render(request, 'forms/newstudentcheck_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is my test code to see if query is working correctly and i keep getting a error that the query set doesnt exists.

```py
from .models import StudentCheck
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from forms.forms import NewStudentForm


def NewStudentFormCheckList (request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewStudentForm(request.POST) 
        lastname = StudentCheck.lastname
        number_lastnames = StudentCheck.objects.get(lastname__exact=lastname)


        if form.is_valid():
            newstudent= form.save()
            print (number_lastnames)

     else:
        form = NewStudentForm()    

     return render(request, 'forms/newstudentcheck_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: You can access it with `form.cleaned_data['lastname']`.

Comment: Though you may prefer to handle it in form validation, you can also prevent duplicates by setting [unique=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#unique) on your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the entries in the database which have a given value already set using the field lookup `exact` (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#exact) for more informations).

In your case it'll be `StudentCheck.objects.get(lastname__exact=yourvalue)`. This would give you a `QuerySet`, and if you want to know how many entries have the given last name, you have to use `count()` on this `QuerySet` to know how many entries it has.

You can use this solutions in two different places:

1. Directly in the view, when receiving the POST values.
2. In a custom validator, which would be used in the definition of the model (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/validators/) to know how to do)

I would recommend to use the second one, as it would be easier to provide custom information for the user on why it's data where not accepted.

Both of these methods requires the data to be passed to the server to be validated though. Otherwise you can define a view that would receive the lastname and return if it's present already in the database in some way (JSON for example), which would be called using Ajax when the user click on the submit button.

**Edit**:

As per request of OP, here's an example of the custom validator:

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from .models import StudentCheck

def validate_lastname(value):
    number_lastnames = StudentCheck.objects.get(lastname__exact=value)
    if number_lastnames > 0:
        raise ValidationError(
            '%s already exists' % value,
        )
```

Now you can use this custom validator with attribute `validators`, either in the definition of your model or inside the definition of your form like this: `lastname = models.CharField(validators=[validate_lastname])`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Could you write out an example for me to better understand it ?

Comment: An example for which solution?

Comment: Validator seems like the best way the more i read the literature .

Comment: Isn't value suppose to be the lastname field ? How does this grab the value from that field ?

Comment: For some reason i cant on my views.py get to query my queryset. So for example this is what i did to test via console.

Comment: Check out what i just posted, for some reason it wont recognize my query set to print to console.